# bootstrap angular datepicker set ng-model $invalid not change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am Useing Bootstrap angular datepicker in a form to update my model 'User'.

I set this datepicker 'require' property is true. 
UpdateUser.html:

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Birthday</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="birthday" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="user.birthday" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="openDate($event)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </p>
    <span>{{userForm.birthday.$invalid}}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Update</button>
</div>
</form>
```

UserCtrl.js:

```
mainApp.controller("detailCtrl", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, DemoService) {        
  $scope.user = DemoService.get({userId : $routeParams.userId});
  $scope.openDate = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
  };
  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };
});
```

So my question is: 
Why {{userForm.birthday.$invalid}} is true when I first set the 'user.birthday' to the datepicker?

Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DkGEVJ?p=preview

Comment: Can you add a plunker that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Hi @yarons ,Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/DkGEVJ?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is weird, but changing the initial birthday from `'1403575208000'` to `new Date(1403575208000)` fixes this problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wut4sJT5hFcG6EfSYe8t?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different problems that look the same at angular-bootstrap Github forums.

I am using angular-bootstrap version 0.13.0 and I found that the datepicker has the value:

```
userForm.$invalid = true
```

when the date field is empty and other situations, and does not work well.

When you want to validate it, problems arise. In such cases, to avoid datepicker validation I used the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$error['required'] !== undefined">Update</button>
</div>
```

Here is my plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sqog7OqudQkww9WsCUT2?p=preview

There you can see the value of userForm.$error and decide to use ng-required=true or false at 'birthday'.

Hope it helps!